# WebBrowser.LoadCompleted and WebBrowser.ScriptNotify not called for a NavigateToString

Tags: silverlight, webbrowser-control, user-agent, notify

I'm trying to get UserAgent on Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight).

```
var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
webBrowser.Navigating += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine("Navigating");
webBrowser.Navigated += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine("Navigated");
webBrowser.NavigationFailed += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine("NavigationFailed");
webBrowser.LoadCompleted += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine("LoadCompleted");
webBrowser.ScriptNotify += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine("ScriptNotify");
webBrowser.NavigateToString(@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body onload=""window.external.notify(navigator.userAgent);""></body></html>");
```

But not a single event is fired (neither Navigating, Navigated, NavigationFailed, LoadCompleted or ScriptNotify).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue. webBrowser was destructed before any event could fire. Simply storing it is fine and events get fired:

```
static WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
```